# How to load a *.DATA file into R workspace

Tags: r

I am trying to load a something.data file into my r workspace, so I can work with the data inside.
However, when I typed `load('something.')`

```
> load('something.data')
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be
In addition: Warning message:
file 'something.data' has magic number '"team'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

what should I do to load this file correctly in my workspace?

Comment: It doesn't sounds like that's an rdata file. Do you mean to be using read.table instead? There's not standard "DATA" file format so you'll have to tell us what's in it.

Comment: $ ls
babies.csv  ex1_tests.Rda  ex3.r  test.data
ex1.r       ex2.r          ex4.r  world_cup.data    I want load the world_cup.data into R workspace, I can do load('ex1_tests.Rda'), but I can not do load('world_cup.data')

Comment: But what's *in* the file? `load()` is not the usual way to get data into R. Normally you import delimited text file with `read.table`

Comment: whats in the file is some info about the world cup, 32 teams, their goals, scores, red cards etc. based on them, I need to do some calculation.

Comment: thanks, I got it. just set my.table <- read.table('world_cup.data') thats should be fine, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `read.table("file name here")`

Comment: May I ask one more basic question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
filevar<-read.table("file.data", sep=",", header=FALSE)
filevar[1:10,]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

how to Load the rdata in R workspace
before using the load function
install **tidyr** and **dplyr** packages.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
load("D:/new/filename.rdata")
```

Comment: the original question was due to a confusion between a `.rda`/`.RData` format file (R-specific binary save file) and a text-format (space-separated) data file.  It's not clear what your answer adds: the OP specifically stated that `load(...)` didn't work for them. Also not at all clear how the tidyverse package loading helps here ... `load()` is part of base R, not in the `dplyr` or `tidyr` packages ...